# Mac OS X 10.6 Annoying Drag and Drop Behavior

Tags: macos, mac, file-transfer

In OS X 10.6 dragging a file(or folder) over another folder in Finder at first highlights that folder and allows you to drop it into the folder as one would imagine. The problem arises after about a second when it then removes the option to drag it over the folder and opens a new finder window with the contents of that folder for you to drag the file into.

I personally find this feature very annoying and it often leads to me moving/copying files into a location I did not intend. I searched through `com.apple.Finder` for 'drag', 'drop', 'move', etc. with no luck.

Does anyone know if there is a way to turn this off?

Answer (score 4):

On **Mac OS X Catalina** the option for this drag and drop behavior can be found under:

***System Preferences*** → ***Accessibility*** → ***Pointer Control*** → ***Spring-loaded delay***.

Disabling the ***Spring-loaded delay*** does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This option is called "spring loaded folders and windows". To disable it, go to Finder -> Preferences, then uncheck the box for this option, or drag the slider out to "long".